# Kotlin throwable BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I was trying to get info from this api in my kotlin app
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR
but when i run it i get the onFailure: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

this is my code:

the class MyData:

```
package com.example.myapplication
data class MyData(

val BTC: Double,

val EUR: Double,

val USD: Double
)
```

this is my ApiInterface:

```
package com.example.myapplication
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET
interface ApiInterface {
@GET("data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR")

fun getData(): Call<List<MyData>>
```

}

And this is is my MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle

import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import java.lang.StringBuilder

const val Base_Url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var txtId: TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    getMyData();

    txtId = findViewById(R.id.txtId)


}

private fun getMyData() {
    val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(Base_Url)
        .build()
        .create(ApiInterface::class.java)

    val retrofitData = retrofitBuilder.getData()

    retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<List<MyData>?> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<MyData>?>, response: Response<List<MyData>?>) {

            val responseBody = response.body()!!

            val myStringBuilder = StringBuilder()
            for (MyData in responseBody) {
                myStringBuilder.append(MyData.BTC)
            }

            txtId.text = myStringBuilder

        }



        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<MyData>?>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "onFailure: "+t.message)


        }
    })
}
```

}

and i get:
com.example.myapplication D/MainActivity: onFailure: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

I really hope someone could help me with it!

Answer (score 1):

Please change the function signature in the `ApiInterface` to:

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR")
    fun getData(): Call<MyData>
}
```

JSON you expect is looking like this:

```
{"BTC":0.07761,"USD":3334.47,"EUR":2923.18}
```

It is neither an array or list, it is an object, so you need to return an object from that function `Call<MyData>`, not a list of objects `Call<List<MyData>>`.

In `MainActivity`:

```
retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<MyData?> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<MyData?>, response: Response<MyData?>) {

        val responseBody = response.body()
        val myStringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        if (responseBody != null) {
            myStringBuilder.append(responseBody.BTC)
        }

        txtId.text = myStringBuilder

    }



    override fun onFailure(call: Call<MyData?>, t: Throwable) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onFailure: "+t.message)

    }
})
```

Comment: and what should i do with retrofitData.enqueue() than?

Comment: change all occurrences of `Call<List<MyData>>` on `Call<MyData>`

Comment: please see my edited answer

Comment: the exception is gone now, but i dont see the output in the textview i pushed my code on this github repo https://github.com/robbe-delsoir/Herexamen